# Secondary structure assignment tool

Tags: protein-structure, webservice

Is there any CA-based online tool/web-server available for secondary structure assignment of proteins except DSSP or STRIDE?

---

[DSSP](https://swift.cmbi.umcn.nl/gv/dssp/) is a database of secondary structure assignments (and much more) for all protein entries in the Protein Data Bank (PDB)

[STRIDE](http://webclu.bio.wzw.tum.de/cgi-bin/stride/stridecgi.py) Protein secondary structure assignment with stride, Basic assignment, Visual assignment, Contact map, Ramachandran Plot